# gdb start tracing from the frame up in the call stack

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want to trace the sequence of calls from frame -5 (frame 5)  to 0 (current position). So first I want to go to frame 5 and then move down to frame 0 by doing single stepping to understand the code flow. I tried to do `frame 5` and then `next` , but `next` is taking me to next line in current (frame 0) function.

Comment: To climb up and down in the stack use the commands `up` and `down` ... :-)

Comment: There's no single `gdb` command that does that. You may want to try `finish` 5 times to leave 5 nested function calls, and `next` from there.